# Getting Error while installing grass extension

Tags: grass-gis, grass-7.0

I want to install grass extension r.stream.order in my grass 7.But,while installing I am getting below error:

```
g.extension -s extension=r.stream.distance url=                                 
Fetching <r.stream.distance> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
Installing...
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file
'/usr/lib/grass72/docs/html/r.stream.distance.html':
Permission denied
make: *** [install] Error 1
WARNING: Installation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
```

Comment: May be you should run with sudo?

Comment: tried with sudo but grass console does'nt ask for password.

Comment: and if you put command in a script and launch it in a linux terminal?