# GRASS: Installing add-ons and mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib64/bin’: Permission denied

Tags: grass-gis, linux

GRASS: Installing add-ons and getting `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib64/bin’: Permission denied`.

---

Example:

```
g.extension extension=r.in.pdal                                                 
Fetching <r.in.pdal> from GRASS GIS Addons repository (be patient)...
Compiling...
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/usr/lib64/bin’: Permission
denied
make: *** [/usr/lib64/grass78/include/Make/Rules.make:16:
/usr/lib64/bin] Error 1
ERROR: Compilation failed, sorry. Please check above error messages.
```

---

This suggests that GRASS needs to be provided sudo rights. Or it might have to be installed elsewhere.

Any ideas what to do?

---

Related:

[Getting Error while installing grass extension](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/252884/getting-error-while-installing-grass-extension)

---

Operating system:

```
ID_LIKE="opensuse suse"
VERSION_ID="20220303"
PRETTY_NAME="openSUSE Tumbleweed"
```

Answer (score 0):

**Possible temporary solution**:

When GRASS is ran, then notice that it also runs a terminal session:

```
Starting GRASS GIS...
Cleaning up temporary files...

          __________  ___   __________    _______________
         / ____/ __ \/   | / ___/ ___/   / ____/  _/ ___/
        / / __/ /_/ / /| | \__ \\_  \   / / __ / / \__ \
       / /_/ / _, _/ ___ |___/ /__/ /  / /_/ // / ___/ /
       \____/_/ |_/_/  |_/____/____/   \____/___//____/

Welcome to GRASS GIS 7.8.6
GRASS GIS homepage:                      https://grass.osgeo.org
This version running through:            Bash Shell (/bin/bash)
Help is available with the command:      g.manual -i
See the licence terms with:              g.version -c
See citation options with:               g.version -x
If required, restart the GUI with:       g.gui wxpython
When ready to quit enter:                exit

Launching <wxpython> GUI in the background, please wait...
GRASS 7.8.6 (newLocation):~ >
```

Using this prompt, write:

```
sudo mkdir /usr/lib64/bin
```

Then give your password.

Then install your add-on (I was trying to install r.in.pdal).

Answer (score 0):

That's not the correct way to install addons. You should not need admin rights at any stage (unless you are setting up a central lab installation for multiple users...).
When you start GRASS, at the command prompt check the GRASS_ADDON_BASE environment variable. On my machine:

```
micha@RMS:~$ env | grep ADDON
GRASS_ADDON_BASE=/home/micha/.grass7/addons
```

If you get something different, then the GRASS startup is somehow not working. Try to set that variable:

```
export GRASS_ADDON_BASE=/home/<your_home_dir/.grass7/addons
```

then rerun the g.extension module

Comment: The behavior I give is the default what occurs after installing GRASS in OpenSuse Tumbleweed, and then installing an add-on using this guide: https://grass.osgeo.org/download/addons/#Common-user

Comment: I do get: `GRASS 7.8.6 (newLocation):~ > env | grep ADDON`
`GRASS_ADDON_BASE=/home/mavavilj/.grass7/addon`. Still the original problem persists.

Comment: Weird.
Do you get the same error with other extensions?